# How to create bins in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bins

I have a data frame named `cst` with columns `country`, `ID`, and `age`. I want to make bins for `age` (divide all ID's into deciles or quartiles) for each separate country. I used this way:

```
cut(cst[!is.na(cst$age), "age"], quantile(cst["age"], probs = seq(0,1,0.1), na.rm = T))
```

However, it makes bins for all data frame, but I need for each country separately.
Could you help me?

Comment: Thanks @RLave, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try with a `dplyr` solution, this would look someithing like this:

```
library(dplyr)
cst2 <- cst %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(
    bin = cut(age, quantile(age, probs=seq(0,1,0.1), na.rm=TRUE))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: While creating bins, I wanted to chose specific break points and let the labels (a simple sequence) adjust based on the break points selected but I get an error that the length of break and labels is different.  


#series

z <- rnorm(100)

# break points

brk <- seq(min(z),max(z), by = 0.5)

#break label

lbl <- seq(1,length(brk), by = 1)

cut(z, breaks = brk, labels = lbl)

if you check length(lbl) == length(brk)   you get TRUE

Any idea why do I get this error

Error in cut.default(z, breaks = brk, labels = lbl) : lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ

Comment: This seems to be a mistake in the documentation, breaks needs to be one longer than labels.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to apply a subset before using the `cut`. It also does not employ the `dplyr` library.

```
for (c in unique(as.list(cst$country))) {
  sub <- subset(cst, country == c)
  cut(sub[!is.na(sub$age), "age"], quantile(sub["age"], probs = seq(0,1,0.1), na.rm = T))
}
```